# Multiple instances of object based on one FXML

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm still pretty new to this so I did quite a reseach but couldn't found any suitable solution on SO or on the interet. How can I create multiple instances of object (you can call it a factory) based on one `.fxml` file.
This particular `.fxml` file represents one record of movie information. And the result looks similar to this (I won't post here the fxml code, because it's not relevant):
[image]

So this is one record. As you can see I need sort of template. Let's say I got to display information about 5 movies, so I wish I could do :

```
    MovieView movieView = new MovieView(name, imageUrl, year, List<String> directors, 
    List<String> actors, Integer boxOffice, reviews);
    movieView.setImage(new Image(...));  // image change
    vbox.getChildren().add(movieView); // append to main panel
```

five times and fill the VBox with five instances of the same class MovieView. How can this be done?

Comment: Study the oracle tutorial: [4 Creating a Custom Control with FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/custom_control.htm).  It tells you exactly what you need to do.  Also see the section [custom components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#fxmlloader) or the fxml intro doc.  The key is using `fx:root`.

Answer (score 1):

[new](https://www.javatpoint.com/new-keyword-in-java#:%7E:text=The%20Java%20new%20keyword%20is,to%20create%20the%20array%20object.) keyword creates a new instance of an object in java.

Each call to `new MovieView(....)` will create a new instance of it.  So if you need 5 instances, you would create it 5 times.

For example, you can do something like this to create 5 movie views and add them to a list

```
 List<MovieView> movieViews = new ArrayList<>();
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     // Creates a new instance on each iteration
     MovieView movieView = new MovieView(...);
     movieViews.add(movieView)
 }
```

Depending on your use case you'll have to pass in appropriate arguments and potentially create new instances of `Image` for each movie.  Also, 5 could be any number here depending on how many instances you need.  You can pass it as an argument to your method.  This example should give you a starting point on how to implement your solution.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it's pretty much useless. You missed my point. I need to know how to "connect" my `MoviewView.fxml` and MovieView class - you can call it controller. But I'm not sure if that's the way contollers work.

Comment: @user7303261, just to remind you: There is no answer "useless" in this platform. If someone is missing your point means, you have not explained your question/issue properly. Do read how to [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) before posting a question.

Comment: @user7303261 The only sense in which this answer is “useless” is in the sense that you can’t be bothered to take the time to understand it.

Comment: If this answer is combined with the info in the duplicate, I think it provides an exact solution to the question as I understood it.